# value of timer Count down is not updating immediately in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, countdown, countdowntimer

I am using the timer_count_down package. (https://pub.dev/packages/timer_count_down) when I restart my timer with a new value(timer seconds). the timer starts with an old value than it restarts with a new value. in short, my state is not updating immediately. and timer restarts with the old value. please help me out from this.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Countdown(
  controller: contrl,//controller for timer
  seconds: time, //time is a state which store seconds.
  build: (BuildContext context, double time) => Text(time.toString()),
  interval: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
  onFinished: () {
    time = 30;//new time updated for timer
    contrl.restart();// this will restart mytimer// but timer is not taking new value it restarts with old value//
  },
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems the package is not designed to be used this way (onFinished -> restart). It is not a clean workaround but you can try the following

```
Countdown(
        controller: contrl, //controller for timer
        seconds: time, //time is a state which store seconds.
        build: (BuildContext context, double time) => Text(time.toString()),
        interval: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        onFinished: () {
          //new time updated for timer
          setState(() {
            time = 10;
          });
          Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) {
            contrl.restart();
          });

          // this will restart mytimer// but timer is not taking new value it restarts with old value//
        },
      ),
```

Or implement your own countdown logic like this:

```
class NewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewPageState createState() => _NewPageState();
}

class _NewPageState extends State<NewPage> {
  Duration time = Duration(seconds: 3);
  Timer _timer;

  void startTimer(Duration reStartTime, Duration interval) {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(interval, (Timer t) {
      if (time <= Duration()) {
        setState(() {
          time = reStartTime;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          time -= interval;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          startTimer(Duration(seconds: 30), Duration(milliseconds: 100));
        },
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text('$time')),
    );
  }
}
```